# webpack module loaders: exclude file in subfolder

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

I have a npm lib and am build an example for it.

the project look like

```
 react-outline
├─ example
│ └── webpack.config.js
│ └── .babelrc
│ └── index.js
├ index.jslib source 
└ README.md
```

The user will `cd` in the "example" folder and run `npm start`

The example/index.js uses React but /index.js(the lib) does not.

- I am accessing the **lib** via webpack > resolve > alias

Now can I fix the error: `Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory "/www/my-npm-lib"`

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require("path");
module.exports = {
  target:"web",
  resolve:{
    alias:{
      'my-npm-lib':__dirname+'/../../index.js'
    }
  },
  module:{
      loaders:[{
                  test: /\.js$/,
                  loader:"babel-loader",
                  exclude:[path.resolve(__dirname,'/../../index.js'),"/node_modules/"],
                  query:{
                      presets:["react", "es2015"]
                  }
              }]
  }
};
```

**.bablerc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "es2015"],
    "react"
  ],
  "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": ["es2015","react"]
      }
  }
}
```

FYI: I am using React Storybook for the example

Comment: did you try to configure external ? https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Hi Jose, I change "resolve:{alias:" to "externals" but get `invalid regular expression flag`
The really strange thing is this error show on first page load, BUT hot-reload fixes the error on source change and everything works? 
I guess the webpack works but the bable is wrong?

Comment: @JoséQuintoZamora The externals is including **a file** in the build.. that only says `module.exports = /home/user/www/my-npm-lib/index.js;` because this is not valid javascript. I am getting the **Error** `invalid regular expression flag` Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
exclude: /node_modules\/(?!(index)\/).*/
```